# Is my Postfix mailserver an open relay?

Tags: postfix

Postfix newbie question: If I use the default, relay_transport = relay (by commenting out the error line), does that make me an open relay? Or does the inet_interfaces fix it?

```
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
# default_transport = error
# relay_transport = error
```

In general, can someone clarify what these two flags do? I have a hard time understanding the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to verify either way there are a couple of open relay testing tools which should help.

Heres a couple:

[checkor.com](http://www.checkor.com/)

[Network abuse clearing house](http://www.abuse.net/relay.html)

Comment: It appears neither of those sites work anymore. The Abuse.net site was taken down some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

The default value of `relay_transport` is `relay`. So as per the documentation, mails will be delivered to the domains listed in `relay_domains`

Now what is `relay_domains`?
- Destination domains and subdomains the system will relay mails to.

The default value for `relay_domains` parameter is `$mydestination`

The default value for `$mydestination` is `localhost`, so the mails are deliverd to the same system.

That implies you don't have an open relay.

P.S. Any postfix gurus around? CMIIAW